# Can laravel queue get rid of max_execution_time=30 secs timeout seeting in php ini in capnel?

Tags: laravel

Currently, users get a timeout issues when uploading a large CSV file.
So, we planned to move on laravel queue. My question is, can laravel queue solve that type of timeout issue when running in the background? Or it will also time out if the file takes more time than 30 sec to finish the execution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the good answer on this is to reduce the file size or maybe use chunk before running on queue. You can also adjust the timeout execution of a job in Laravel queue by calling the [timeout](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#main-content) and set a value

```
`<?php
 
namespace App\Jobs;
 
class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue
{ 
/**
     * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 120;
}`
```

Comment: Isn't it cause server busy issue? I want to keep the default timeout 30 sec but upload a 10+ MB file.